# How can I make my js slider move the opposite direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my slider move in the opposite direction, but I can't figure out how to make it move right to left, instead it's moving left to right. I can get it to go right to left, but the problem I'm encountering is with the right to left movement, it doesn't stay a full grid, instead their is a mysterious gap between the two. With the left to right method, the grid moves as one huge block without any interruptions.

How can I make it so that my slider goes right to left and stops at the last li, and only go back with left arrow instead of doing a full wrap around by just pressing right/button?

http://jsfiddle.net/YDSWA/2/ (use arrow keys right and left to move slider)

Below is the jS for my slider and the jsFiddle has the CSS and HTML.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    $('#slider').css({
        width: slideWidth,
        height: slideHeight
    });
    $('#slider ul').css({
        width: sliderUlWidth,
        marginLeft: -slideWidth
    });
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            right: -slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#slider ul li').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('right', '');
        })
    }
    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            right: -slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('right', '');
        })
    }
    $('#back').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    })
    $('#next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    })

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            moveRight();
        } else {

        }
    })
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            moveLeft();
        } else {
        }
    })
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iJEYeRE/1/)**

**jQ:**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $sl = $('#slider'),
        $ul = $('ul', $sl),
        $li = $('li', $ul),
        slideCount  = $li.length,
        slideWidth  = $li.width(),
        slideHeight = $li.height(),
        sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $sl.css({width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight});
    $ul.css({width: sliderUlWidth});

    function moveLeft() {
      $ul.not(':animated').prepend( $('li:last-child', $ul) )
      .css({left:-slideWidth})
      .animate({left:0}, 700);
    }
    function moveRight() {
        $ul.not(':animated').animate({left: -slideWidth}, 700, function() {
          $(this).css({left: 0}).append( $('li:first-child', this) );
        });
    }

    $('#back, #next').click(function() {
        return this.id=='next' ? moveRight() : moveLeft();
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var k = e.which;
        if( k==39 || k==37 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            return k==39? moveRight() : moveLeft();  
        }
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.uni_con {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#cf5;
}
#slider ul {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    list-style: none;
    background:#f00;
}
#slider ul li {
    float: left;
    background: none;
    width: 1200px;
    background:#555;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
#slider img {
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a boss for figuring this out! :3

Comment: I just started learning jS last week, and I exhausted all the ways to get the slider move like a full grid like your example, but I couldn't get it right. Thanks, a lot! :P

Comment: @Monstr92 oh, no problem, you're pretty good if it's just a week! If you have questions concerning my code, don't hesitate to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, I really like your syntax formatting. My only question is, how can I add an if statement so that when the user hits the last li (second page), they can't wrap around by to the first, and are forced to use the back button?

Comment: @Monstr92 gimme a minute to show you in an online demo please.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you for helping me out :D. I just bought a jS book off Amazon, but it hasn't be published yet. (it's the Jon Duckket jS book.)

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot! :3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40082/discussion-between-monstr92-and-roko-c-buljan)